# How can I disable Implicit Conversion in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide, implicit-conversion

Implicit conversions when using DateTime/DateTimeOffset, or int/decimal variables can cause unexpected behaviors at runtime, so I would prefer to raise warning or errors at compile time when such a conversion is detected.

How can I achieve that in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Can you give an example of implicit conversion causin unexpected runtime behavior? As far as I know, *implicit* conversions are designed to be safe.

Comment: Comparing DateTime and DateTimeOffset values around daylight saving time changes would not be safe (cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/11/28/time-travel-with-net-or-datetime-datetimeoffset-and-the-lost-dst-hour-greg.aspx).

Comment: I would like to see an example of such behavior, with exact definitions of what you expect and what you get.

Comment: DateTime values around daylight saving time changes are "unsafe" in general. Two DateTime values that represent different points in time may compare equal. Warning about implicit conversions would not help you, as that would give the wrong result without any implicit conversion.

Comment: True, actually it would help me detect improper use of DateTime as a side effect.

Comment: But to me the following doesn't make sense anyway: 
                var dto1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 30, 2, 30, 0);
                var dto2 = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 10, 30, 2, 30, 0, new TimeSpan(5,0,0));
                var b = dto1 == dto2;
As we are comparing a datetime with no offset with another that has an offset.

Comment: @ErwinMayer Sadly, it's not a datetime with no offset, it's a datetime with (depending on `datetime.Kind`) an offset of 0 or based on your local time zone. Because the offset can be determined from your datetime, the conversion to `DateTimeOffset` can be considered safe. IMO, this is a design flaw in `DateTime`, and in your case, you may be better off not using `DateTime` at all. That's something that you should be able to search for with less difficulty than the conversion you wish to warn for.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev they can very easily cause run-time errors. We added more params to each overload for some functions and tried to ensure we changed the actual calls properly.  However, we found run-time errors converting Strings to Longs...the compiler 'thought' that we were using a different overload and did not produce a warning / error for the conversion from String to Long, so they were hard to find and ONLY presented at run time.  They may be designed to be 'safe', but they are not always - as they cannot be perfectly relied upon, they are simply useful and convenient most of the time.

Comment: @Grantly I don't quite believe you. There's no implicit conversion from `string` to `long`.

Comment: lol...So 'implicit conversion' (the Compile option within your VB.NET project properties) skips Strings and Long?  Base types are implicitly converted all the time, try it...But I'm not here to prove it to you..Ask a question if you want 'answers' or proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not possible to disable implicit conversions in C#.**

However, Visual Basic can disable them using `Option Strict On`.